# Я не понимаю, как ограничить размер при вводе до 250птс, чтобы больше 250 эллипс не строился

Tags: html

вот код

```
 <h1 align=center>Построение эллипса
  <BR/>
</h1>
<TABLE BORDER=0>
  <THEAD>
    <TR>Задайте длины полуосей</TR>
  </THEAD>
  <TR>
    <TD>Горизонтальная x=</TD>
    <TD>
      <INPUT type="number" name="A" ID="A" onkeydown="handleKeydown(event)" />
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>Вертикальная y=</TD>
    <TD>
      <INPUT type="number" name="B" ID="B" onkeydown="handleKeydown(event)" />
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD> &nbsp; </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <INPUT type="BUTTON" value='ПОСТРОИТЬ' onclick="draw_ellipse()" />
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<div ID="K" style=" position:absolute;  top: 100px;  left:500px;  height:500px;  width:500px;  background-color:#AFEEEE">
</div>
<script>
function draw_ellipse() { //D=document.forms[0].D.value
  var A = document.getElementById('A').value
  var B = document.getElementById('B').value
  sEllipse = '<svg height="500" width="500">' +
    '<ellipse cx="250" cy="250" rx="' + A + '" ry="' + B + '" style="fill:#FF00FF;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />' +
    '<line x1="250" y1="0" x2="250" y2="500" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />' +
    '<line x1="0" y1="250" x2="500" y2="250" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />' +
    '</svg>'
  document.getElementById('K').innerHTML = sEllipse
}

function handleKeydown(e) {
  if (e.key == '-')
    e.preventDefault();
}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если по простому - добавляем проверку и если не проходит останавливаем скрипт.

```
function draw_ellipse() { //D=document.forms[0].D.value
 var A = document.getElementById('A').value
 var B = document.getElementById('B').value
 if (A > 250 || B > 250) {
   alert('Максимальное значение не больше 250')
   return
 }
 sEllipse = '<svg height="500" width="500">' +
   '<ellipse cx="250" cy="250" rx="' + A + '" ry="' + B + '" style="fill:#FF00FF;stroke:purple;stroke-width:2" />' +
   '<line x1="250" y1="0" x2="250" y2="500" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />' +
   '<line x1="0" y1="250" x2="500" y2="250" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />' +
   '</svg>'
 document.getElementById('K').innerHTML = sEllipse
```

}

Comment: огромное спасибо вам

Comment: Если это вам помогло можете отметить как правильный ответ)